# Enabling filename completion in a new vim command

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In vim, I want to create a new command that takes a file-name as its single argument.
Is there a way to create such a command, so that the file-name-completion-magic (using tab) will work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `-complete=file` in the command arguments.

```
:help :command-completion
```

For example:

```
:command -complete=file -nargs=1 OpenFile e <args>
```

Comment: Can you specify the path for the files to be loaded from though?